# How can I use a local repository in the vendor in Google Cloud Functions with Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, go-modules

I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function written in Go.

By doing some research I found out that vendor files are prefered over go.mod so I'm vendoring everything I use (which includes some local dependencies) and ignoring the go.mod/sum files in the .gcloudignore file.

The problem is that after trying to deploy, I get the following error:

```
go: nimbus@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: parsing /nimbus/go.mod: open /nimbus/go.mod: no such file or directory; Error ID: 03a1e2f7
```

nimbus is my local dependency and it has the following structure:

[image: local repository structure]

My Function repository has the following structrure:

[image]

and my go.mod file is:

```
module my_function

go 1.13

require nimbus v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000

replace nimbus => ../../../nimbus
```

I've tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441096 already. But it did not fix my issue.

I've tried everything to solve this issue, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does your nimbus dependency is specific to the project of the Cloud Function?

Comment: What research results brought you to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was very complicated and I hope Google finds a solution for it asp.

By deploying my function using Cloud Build, It would read from my repository on Google Source, but, by reading from there it would bypass the .gcloudignore file and deploy both the go.mod/sum files and the vendor directory with my local code.

As said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050872/10316247:

> If you have a go.mod file and a vendor directory, the vendor directory will be ignored when you deploy your function.

So the error would occur because of my go.mod not being able to find local repository.

My solution was to rename my go.mod/sum files so it would not be considered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a go.mod file and a vendor directory, the vendor directory will be ignored when you deploy your function.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go

I have used modules when deploying GCP functions in Go. Haven't had any problems. But I can't speak to the preference of using vendor/ instead. It should work, just without the go.mod file.

Comment: Cold start is the main reason. Loading dependencies, rather than having them locally makes your cold start time much longer (in some cases, depending on the dependencies, a LOT longer).

Comment: also, as said in the question and shown in the picture of the project structure the .gcloudignore file should be ignoring both go.mod and go.sum files an by doing so only considering the vendor file

Answer (score 0):

When you use golang 1.16 and specify golang 1.16 in the go.mod folder it will instead default to using the vendor files with the `--mod=vendor` flag set, which will solve this issue.

You'll just need to ensure your module name is formatted correctly (something like example.com/module).

Comment: To improve on the answer, I would link to relevant documentation for the parts that the OP missed.